# Iterate through cells in a column, if contains criteria, copy row to new sheet

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have a spreadsheet similar to the following:

```
Name       Title        ID
Person 1    Title 1     1
Person 2    Title 2     11
Person 3    Title 3     111
Person 4    Title 4     1111
Person 5    Title 5     12
Person 6    Title 6     121
Person 7    Title 7     1211
Person 8    Title 8     1212
Person 9    Title 9     122
Person 10   Title 10    13
Person 11   Title 11    131
Person 12   Title 12    1311
Person 13   Title 13    1312
Person 14   Title 14    13121
Person 15   Title 15    1313
Person 16   Title 16    132
Person 17   Title 17    1321
Person 18   Title 18    14
Person 19   Title 19    15
Person 20   Title 20    151
Person 21   Title 21    1512
```

I want to iterate through each cell in the "ID" column. 
If the column contains a value, then copy the entire row to a new sheet.

Here's the tricky part:

```
 - The first number will always start with 1. 
 - I want the script to search "ID" for 1 + another single digit (10,11,12,13...). 
   For all cells that match the criteria copy that row to a new sheet. 
 - When that is done, now search for 11 + another single digit (111,112,113,114...). 
 - When that is done, now search for 12 + another digit (121,122,123,124...)
```

This should keep going:

```
Search "ID" for:    Finds all:
    19              191, 192, 193, 194...
    124            1241, 1242, 1243, 1244...
    1111            11111, 11112, 11113, 11114, 11115...
    1127           11271, 11272, 11273, 11274... 
    12345           123451, 123452, 123453, 123454, 123455...
```

The preceding digits before the '+ another single digit' dictate what sheet it should go in.

```
 - If search for 1 + another single digit - these should all go on a single sheet.
 - If searching for 11 + another single digit - these should go on a single sheet.
 - If search for 1234 + another single digit - these should go on a single sheet.
 - So on and so forth.
```

Comment: @findwindow I have added my code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize I should have posted my attempt at it before asking. Anyway, I figured out how to do it. I am new to VBA but this worked:

```
Set mainSht = Worksheets("Sheet1")  ' Copy From this sheet

'Find the last row with data in specified column.
LR = mainSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

Set LRange = mainSht.Range("F2:F" & LR)

'Find max number in the range
max = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(LRange)

'Look at every cell in cpecified column
For Each Cell In LRange
 For i = 1 To max

    cIndex = CStr(i)

    If Cell.Value Like "1" + cIndex + "?" Then    'check to See if C equals value                                       
        sheetName = "1" + cIndex

        'Check if worksheet exists
        Set wsCheck = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wsCheck = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)
        On Error GoTo 0

        'If worksheet does not exist, create new
        If wsCheck Is Nothing Then
            Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = sheetName
        End If

Set Pastesheet = Worksheets(sheetName)  ' Paste to this sheet
            Cell.EntireRow.Copy  ' Copy the row
            Pastesheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    End If
    Next

Next Cell  ' Now we check the next cell in chosen column
```